# Visual Studio 2010 precompile or prebuild actions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, prebuild, precompiling

I'm looking for ability to make some replacements in my code files in prebuild or precompile phase (user transparent). I was thinking about Visual Studio extension, but haven't found solution yet. Some way to access all files in solution/project or at least it' path is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built-in pre-build actions in Visual Studio (as are post-build), wouldn't they be suitable for your needs?

More information here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: it's sort of solution but for sure it's not user transparent, what is more you have to specify these event for every project thru properties windows (as far i know it can be achived by editing .csproj file too). i want to make that action automated for every kind of project, that's why i was thinking about VS extension.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a project template would be more suitable? Or putting all the pre-build actions in one utility with minimum configuration and setting up each project to run this utility as a pre-build event?